# Group rdd based on a value in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I have created an rdd and print the results with:

```
finalRDD = replacetimestampRDD.map(lambda x: (x[1], x[0:]))
print("Partitions structure: {}".format(finalRDD.glom().collect()))
```

Output (an example):

```
Partitions structure: [[('a', ['2020-05-22 15:17:10', 'John', '9535175']), 
                        ('b', ['2020-05-22 15:17:10', 'Nick', '7383554',]),
                        ('c', ['2020-05-22 15:17:10', 'George', '8915433']),
                        ('a', ['2020-05-22 15:17:10', 'Paul', '9615224'])
                      ]]
```

I try to group the results by key (by key I mean 'a','b','c'). Desired output:

```
Partitions structure: [[('a', [['2020-05-22 15:17:10', 'John', '9535175'],['2020-05-22 15:17:10', 'Paul', '9615224']]), 
                        ('b', ['2020-05-22 15:17:10', 'Nick', '7383554',]),
                        ('c', ['2020-05-22 15:17:10', 'George', '8915433'])
                          ]]
```

I try with `results = finalRDD.groupByKey().collect()` but it doesn't seem to work?

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Is the structure of your RDD a list of lists? the example output you gave, does it show a single output element or is it supposed to show a list with 4 elements?

Comment: yes, the structure is as shown a list of lists. the example output must be a list with 4 elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `mapValues()` after `groupByKey()` to create a list off values:

```
rdd.groupByKey().mapValues(list).collect()
```

Output:

```
[('a',
  [['2020-05-22 15:17:10', 'John', '9535175'],
   ['2020-05-22 15:17:10', 'Paul', '9615224']]),
 ('b', [['2020-05-22 15:17:10', 'Nick', '7383554']]),
 ('c', [['2020-05-22 15:17:10', 'George', '8915433']])]
```